# Rows disappearing when using sum with group_by

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to reduce a dataframe by grouping the data by three columns. The original data is:

```
dput(coupler)
structure(list(Category = c("SSC", "SSC", "SSC", "SSC", "SSC", 
"SSC", "SSC", "SSC", "HBC", "HBC", "HBC", "HBC", "HBC", "TC", 
"TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "BSC", "BSC", "BSC", "BSC", "BSC", 
"BSC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", 
"GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC"), `Bar Size` = c("No. 6", 
"No. 8", "No. 6", "No. 8", "No. 4", "No. 10", "No. 8", "No. 4", 
"No. 10", "No. 8", "No. 5", "No. 8", "No. 10", "No. 18", "No. 10", 
"No. 10", "No. 5", "No. 8", "No. 10", "No. 18", "No. 18", "No. 8", 
"No. 5", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 10", "No. 8", "No. 6", "No. 8", 
"No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 18", "No. 18", "No. 5", 
"No. 5", "No. 8", "No. 10", "No. 10"), `No. Bars` = c(12, 12, 
28, 28, 4, 9, 10, 9, 9, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 14, 4, 18, 18, 18, 2, 
2, 3, 12, 1, 11, 12, 6, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 8, 10, 18, 16, 
2), Failure = c("Bar pullout", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", 
"Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", 
"Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", 
"Coupler failure", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Coupler failure"), Researcher = c("Lloyd", "Lloyd", "Lloyd", 
"Lloyd", "Hillis & Saiidi", "Rowell et al.", "Huaco & Jirsa", 
"Alam et al.", "Rowell et al.", "Haber et al.", "Tazarv", "Tazarv", 
"Tazarv", "Noureddine", "Rowell et al.", "Rowell et al.", "Tazarv", 
"Tazarv", "Tazarv", "Noureddine", "Noureddine", "Yang et al.", 
"Tazarv", "Tazarv", "Tazarv", "Tazarv", "Ameli et al.", "Jansson", 
"Haber et al.", "Rowell et al.", "Rowell et al.", "Rowell et al.", 
"Jansson", "Noureddine", "Noureddine", "Tazarv", "Tazarv", "Tazarv", 
"Tazarv", "Tazarv"), Year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2009, 2009, 
2012, 2010, 2009, 2013, 2020, 2020, 2020, 1996, 2009, 2009, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 1996, 1996, 2014, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2015, 2008, 
2013, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 1996, 1996, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I use the following line:

```
coupler.graph <- coupler[,1:4] %>% group_by(Category, `Bar Size`, Failure) %>% 
                             filter(`No. Bars` == sum(`No. Bars`))
```

But the resulted dataframe is missing some rows. I am not sure why this is happening. how can I preserve all the rows and just summarize the rows in common.

Comment: How many rows are missing

Comment: Are you just trying to get groups with 1 row  `%>%  filter(n() == 1)`.  From the example data, I got 22 rows as output.  Is this issue specific to the example or on a bigger data.  `sum` can have issue if there are missing value.  You may need `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: Maybe take a look at `coupler[,1:4] %>% group_by(Category, `Bar Size`, Failure) %>% 
    mutate(grp_ttl = sum(`No. Bars`), unique = `No. Bars` == sum(`No. Bars`))` to see which rows have unique Cat/Size/Failure and which don't.

Comment: @JonSpring That solved it!